# Symfony2 service method used in Twigs layout to soon

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, twig, lazy-loading

I've a service registered for Twig and i use its method in my main `layout.twig.html` to list some things.
Next, in some actions i use the same service to change its state (change some private fields there) and i would like to see those changes in my rendered page. But it looks like Twig invokes the "getter" method to soon, when my data is not yet managed by controller's action.

What is the best practice for such case? Should i somehow use some Events and make my Service kind of event listener?

Example layout code:

```
<div>{{ myservice.mymethod() }}</div>
```

Service:

```
class MyService {
    private $myfield = null;
    ....
    public function setMyField($value) {
        $this->myfield = $value;
    }
    public function myMethod() {
        if($this->myfield === null) {
            return 'not initialized';
        } else {
                $this->myfield;
        }
    }
    ....
```

Some controller action:

```
$myservice = $this->container->get('myservice');
$myservice->setMyField('setted in action');
```

And i always get `not initialized` on rendered page

Comment: What your services.yml looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to register this service as a twig extension.

check out this manual: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html.